# Pass generic parameter to a non-generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

I'm attempting to create a method which will round nullables to a given decimal place.  Ideally I'd like this to be a generic so that I can use it with both Doubles and Decimals as `Math.Round()` permits.

The code I have written below will not compile because the method cannot be (understandably) resolved as it's not possible to know which overload to call.  How would this be achieved?

```
internal static T? RoundNullable<T>(T? nullable, int decimals) where T : struct
{
    Type paramType = typeof (T);

    if (paramType != typeof(decimal?) && paramType != typeof(double?))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type '{0}' is not valid", typeof(T)));

    return nullable.HasValue ? Math.Round(nullable.Value, decimals) : (T?)null; //Cannot resolve method 'Round(T, int)'
 }
```

Comment: +1 interesting, though it's probably easier to just write the two overloads

Comment: Why not using two methods, one for decimal and second one for doubles? In thsi way you can avoid casts and code will be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How would this be achieved?

Personally, I would just get rid of your generic method. It's only valid for two type arguments anyway - split it into an overloaded method with two overloads:

```
internal static double? RoundNullable(double? nullable, int decimals)
{
    return nullable.HasValue ? Math.Round(nullable.Value, decimals)
                             : (double?) null;
}

internal static decimal? RoundNullable(decimal? nullable, int decimals)
{
    return nullable.HasValue ? Math.Round(nullable.Value, decimals)
                             : (decimal?) null;
}
```

If you *must* use the generic version, either invoke it conditionally as per Dave's answer, invoke it with reflection directly, or use `dynamic` if you're using C# 4 and .NET 4.

Comment: Thanks - This did pass my mind, I just thought I'd be doing good for using the features offered to us (generics)

Comment: @m.edmondson: No, it's an *abuse* of the features offered... because it's not a truly generic method; even the constraint you've specified don't really capture how restricted it is. It's a method which is valid for two specific types, and that's all.

Comment: Thanks for that - I did have a nagging feeling that this would be the answer

Comment: where is the use of T? I think the method can be written without generics?

Comment: @Asif: Sorry, yes - I meant it to not be generic, I just missed that bit in the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Given you're already doing a type-check, simply use that in your code flow:

```
if (paramType == typeof(decimal?))
...
    Math.Round((decimal)nullable.Value, decimals)
else if(paramType == typeof(double?))
    Math.Round((double)nullable.Value, decimals)
```